# INVALID_SERVICE Error Code on CAS forced login page

Tags: 8

i have configured a forced login for the `/intranet` page

```
/fr/admin/config/people/cas
```

I have created a menu link to that page `/intranet`

when clicking on it , the cas creadential are asked and it returns an

> INVALID_SERVICE
>    error

```
http://mywebsitedomainfr/casservice?q=fr%2Fcasservice&returnto=http%3A%2F%mywebsitedomain%2Ffr%2Fintranet%3Fq%3Dfr%252Fintranet&ticket=ST-74551-ESB2kMRXfQ5UcMbqajPd-mycasserver||0||Validation response received from CAS server: #012#012#012#012#011#012#011#011Le ticket &#039;ST-74551-ESB2kMRXfQ5UcMbqajPd-mycasserver&#039; ne correspond pas au service demandé. Le service original était &#039;http://mywebsitedomain/fr/casservice?returnto=http%3A//mywebsitedomain/fr/intranet%3Fq%3Dfr%252Fintranet&#039; et le service demandé était &#039;http://mywebsitedomain/fr/casservice?q=fr/casservice&amp;returnto=http%3A//mywebsitedomain/fr/intranet%3Fq%3Dfr%252Fintranet&#039;.
Error when validating ticket: Error Code INVALID_SERVICE: Le ticket 'ST-74551-ESB2kMRXfQ5UcMbqajPd-mycasserveur ne correspond pas au service demandé. Le service original était 'http://mywebsitedomain/fr/casservice?returnto=http%3A//mywebsitedomain/fr/intranet%3Fq%3Dfr%252Fintranet' et le service demandé était 'http://mywebsitedomain/fr/casservice?q=fr/casservice&returnto=http%3A//mywebsitedomain/fr/intranet%3Fq%3Dfr%252Fintranet'.
http://mywebsitedoamin/fr/casservice?q=fr%2Fcasservice&returnto=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsitedomain %2Ffr%2Fintranet%3Fq%3Dfr%252Fintranet&ticket=ST-74551-ESB2kMRXfQ5UcMbqajPd-mycasserverdomain||0||Converting query parameter 'returnto' to 'destination'.
http://mywebsite domain/fr/intranet?q=fr%2Fintranet&q=fr%2Fintranet||0||Temp disable flag set, skipping CAS subscriber.
```

Answer (score 0):

this happened to be a nginx misconfiguration

Comment: Could you please clarify what was misconfigured and how you solved it exactly?

Comment: i dont have the details from the sysadmin, smthg with the q parameter